# Static IP addr for just a particular access point in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, ip-address, static-ip

I want to give my brother-in-law's machine a static IP address when he connects to his wireless access point at home using Vista. When I do, though, it changes it universally, and it breaks him connecting at work. I can't seem to limit it to that particular connection.

On XP this was relatively easy, but Vista seems to be different.

Any help here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the programs listed below to create and manage multiple network profiles.

**[IP Organizer 2](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/iporganizer.html)** does what it says on the tin.

[image]

the website is in Turkish, here's the [download link](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/dosyalar/IP_Organizer2.exe).

*IP Organizer is freeware.*

Here's another one:

**[NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm)** allows you to quickly switch between pre-configured network settings.

[image]

*NetSetMan is free for personal use.*

Answer (score 0):

Can the access point be configured with the MAC address of the wireless card to only issue a specific address by DHCP?  This assumes the work environment is using DHCP as well.